# Как сделать так чтобы код выводил пароль?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Здесь в коде мне надо в генератор списков передать символы из all и сделать срез. Но мне выводит ошибку.

```
import random
import string
num = int(input("enter a lenght of password: "))
all = [lambda: random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase),
      lambda: random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase),
      lambda: random.choice(string.digits)]
passw = "".join([x for x in all][:num])
print(passw)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Добавьте ошибку

Comment: можно было и проще написать генератор паролей...

Answer (score 2):

Самый простой генератор паролей:

```
from string import ascii_letters, digits
from random import choices

lenght_of_password = int(input('Отправьте длину пароля: '))
generated_password = ''.join(choices(ascii_letters+digits, k=lenght_of_password))
print(generated_password)
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас в списке функции, а не строка, поэтому ваш "генератор списков" работает не совсем так как вы ожидаете. И от лямбд и от списков тут можно отказаться. Получится что-то такое:

```
from string import ascii_letters, digits
from random import choice

passw = ''
num = int(input("enter a lenght of password: "))
for _ in range(num):
    passw += choice(ascii_letters + digits)
    
print(passw)
'''
enter a lenght of password: 15
a75V6Ou9Nmjv6fl
```

Answer (score 0):

- не называйте переменную `all`, так вы перекрываете встроенную функцию питона, можете добавить к имени подчёркивание
- у вас список функций, их надо вызвать со скобками `x()`:

```
all_ = ...
passw = "".join([x() for x in all_][:num])
                  ^^          ^^^^
```